# Find last inserted record - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

The database structure is not optimally constructed, so this is about getting the best out of the current condition.

I just want to find the last inserted record using a character field as id

```
CREATE TABLE find
    (id varchar(8),date date);    
INSERT INTO find
    (id,date)
VALUES
    ('X','2017-10-01'),
    ('Y','2017-10-01'),
    ('A','2017-10-01');
```

I want to find the last record that is 'A'

```
SELECT    max(id) 
FROM      find
```

Using the common max gets 'Y' as an answer

What I am looking for is a magic hidden transaction id like

```
SELECT    max(transaction_id) 
FROM      find
```

Three questions:

1. Is it possible to find last record 'A' without timestamp?
2. Does the timestamp "cost" more than a simple date?
3. Other solutions?

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/60b68/1

TIA,

Comment: There is no magical hidden transaction field.  In fact, Postgres doesn't even have to show the `A` record as appearing last, because even if you used `ORDER BY date` it would be free to place those three records in any order whatsoever.  If you need order beyond what `date` can offer, then adding another column would probably be the best long term solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add an auto_increment column and get the MAX() of it. it will show correct result
2. Timestamp compares the time portion also and useful than simple date
3. you can do a `ORDER BY your_date_time_field DESC` and select 1 record but may not get correct result.